# Newtonsoft json: serialize values in object as dictionary keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have an anonymous object like:

```
string keyValue = "keyValue1";
var itemsArray = new [] { .. }

return new
{
   Key = keyValue,
   Items = itemsArray
}
```

That I want to serialize to a string via Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET). I use a default serialization configuration that gives me output like:

```json
{
  "Key": "keyValue1",
  "Items": [{ .. } , .. ]
}
```

that is fine, but I want to have slightly different formatting (without field names from c# class):

```json
{
  "keyValue1" : [{ .. } , .. ]
}
```

I can do it if I create a c# dictionary with a **single** item where a `key` will be `keyValue` and `value` - `itemsArray`, but I hope there is a better way (without creating a single-item dictionary)?

NOTE: I'm fine to replace anonymous class on a regular one if it makes things easier

Comment: Hi, is it possible that your serialized JSON have more than one key-value pair?

Comment: Do you know the `keyValue1` at compile time?

Comment: "_I hope there is a better way (without creating a single-item dictionary)?_" whats wrong with dictionary?

Comment: `Do you know the keyValue1 at compile time` - no, it's a value from a different object

Comment: `whats wrong with dictionary?` - KeyValuePair will be fine,  but dictionary is not really. I'm going to work with this structure further and calling `.Single()` all the time looks like not the best approach

Comment: @YongShun, `is it possible that your serialized JSON have more than one key-value pair? ` - on that level it will be always one key-value pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it in one line

```
var json = new JObject { [keyValue] = new JArray(itemsArray)}.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0) class

Example :

```cs
var key = "keyValue1";
var itemsArray = new[] {"1","2","3" };

IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();
result[key] = itemsArray;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

output

```json
{"keyValue1":["1","2","3"]}
```

**Alternative without Interface `IDictionary`:**

`ExpandoObject` inherits `Object` class so you can add properties to it for example `key` that will have an object array i.e `itemsArray`.

```cs
var itemsArray = new[] {"1","2",new object()};

//create expando object
dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
result.key = itemsArray;

//serialize
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
Console.WriteLine(json);

//get values
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
//values.key allows you to access the contents of the object
```

Output:

```
{"key":["1","2",{}]}
```

Comment: this looks the same as using Dictionary, doesn't it?

Comment: `ExpandoObject`  also implements  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>` ,if you dont want dictionary and want to serialize multiple `KeyValuePair<String,Object>`.

Comment: the key point that I want to have a single object (not collection), ie do not need to call `.Single` all the time when I work with this node further

Comment: @dododo `ExpandoObject` also inherits object class then you can define with a property `key`  and with values of your items